# Firebase RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Below is a firebase read query performance test from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786) question, I just changed it to my own firebase instance and removed sequential test leaving only the parallel one.

The problem is that any time I run this code and I make the for loop `i < 12` resulting in an array of length: `32,768`, I keep getting an error saying that call stack exceeded: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` but I can't figure out what is causing this error... I tried testing it on both localhost and via cloud functions but no success.

*(The referenced SO test works at i<12 but then also breaks if I change it to 13)*.

```
function loadVideosParallel(videoIds, callback) {
  Promise.all(
    videoIds.map((id) => {
      return admin.database().ref("test").child(id).once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
          return snapshot;
        })
    })
  ).then((r) => callback());
}

function loadVideosForUser(loadVideosParallel, callback) {
  admin.database().ref("test").once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    var videoKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val());

    for (var i=0; i < 13; i++) {
      videoKeys = videoKeys.concat(videoKeys);
    }

    loadVideosParallel(videoKeys, function() {
      if (callback) callback();
    });
  })
}

let start = Date.now();
loadVideosForUser(loadVideosParallel, function() {
  const endTime = (Date.now() - start)+'ms';
  console.log('parallel done after '+ endTime +'ms');
});
```

> 2017-12-20T23:26:28.527Z E helloWorld: RangeError: Maximum call stack
>   size exceeded
>       at T (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:139:366)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:190:120
>       at ta (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:45:40)
>       at ua (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:45:89)
>       at Ag (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:190:93)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:195:260
>       at Oc (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:85:363)
>       at Oc (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:85:449)
>       at Oc (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:85:449)
>       at Nc (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:85:316)
>   2017-12-20T23:26:29.758741829Z D helloWorld: Function execution took
>   5107 ms, finished with status: 'crash'

Anybody have any insight? I tried looking at the `/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js` file but it's minified so can't really tell what's going on.

Comment: If you want to look at the unobfuscated code: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node

Comment: I looked there before asking the question but the database/database.ts file there is not the same, it's much much shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'r queueing up more than 32,768 read operations, which is overflowing one of the stacks in the SDK. Loading that many items without any flow control in your code seems like a **bad** idea, so I'm actually quite happy that the SDK cops out. Consider loading the items in batches that are more reasonable.

In general though: try to limit loading thousands of items from the database. If you need that many items for an aggregation operation, you're **much** better off keeping the aggregated value explicitly in the database and updating it with every write operation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why do 32,768 read operations work in the referenced test, after stripping out the sequential part and only testing the parallel one? But if I copy it over to local host or my own cloud function it no longer works?

Comment: The motivation behind the test is that I'm trying to see how fanout-on-read vs fanout-on-write would differ for an activity feed